# IE 10 Submit button bug

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, button

Looking at IE10 my form that was working fine in all browsers now does not work in IE10. Not sure why it is not working at all. I have read it might be .NET problem but not sure how to fix it in my site. Code is below:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="" onclick="verify();" class="review"/>
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell just from showing that input element in isolation, and not mentioning what exactly doesn't work. Can you make a jsfiddle of the issue or point to your actual web page? Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: @dstorey sorry about the lack of information. I fixed it. During my searches I saw a lot of issues with IE10 buttons so was not sure if my submit type was wrong/missing something. I changed up the form so it wasnt nested in one spot and it worked. Again, sorry for the vague question.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the submit type to "type = button".